# SWR hook not reflecting database change

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda, next.js, swr

This component is for counting views at page level in Next.js app deployed on AWS Lambda

```js
function ViewsCounter({ slug }: { slug: string }) {
  const { data } = useSWR(`/api/views/${slug}`, fetcher);
  const views = new Number(data?.total);

  useEffect(() => {
    const registerView = () =>
      fetch(`/api/views/${slug}`, { method: "POST" })
        .catch(console.log);
    registerView();
  }, [slug]);

  return (
    <>
      {views}
    </>
  );
}
```

This one is for displaying views on homepage

```js
function ViewsDisplay({ slug }: { slug: string }) {
  const { data } = useSWR(`/api/views/${slug}`, fetcher);
  const views = new Number(data?.total);

  return (
    <>
      {views}
    </>
  );
}
```

While it works as expected on localhost, looks like it displays only the first fetched value and doesn't revalidate it for some reason.
When visiting the page, Counter is triggered correctly and the value is changed in DB.
Probably it has something to do with mutating, any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`useSWR` won't automatically refetch data by default.

You can either enable automatic refetch using the [`refreshInterval`](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/revalidation#revalidate-on-interval) option.

```js
const { data } = useSWR(`/api/views/${slug}`, fetcher, { refreshInterval: 1000 });
```

Or explicitly update the data yourself using a [mutation](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/mutation) after the POST request to the API.

```js
function ViewsCounter({ slug }: { slug: string }) {
    const { data, mutate } = useSWR(`/api/views/${slug}`, fetcher);
    const views = new Number(data?.total);

    useEffect(() => {
        const registerView = () =>
            fetch(`/api/views/${slug}`, { method: "POST" })
                .then(() => {
                    mutate();
                })
                .catch(console.log);
        registerView();
    }, [slug]);

    return (<>{views}</>);
}
```